# Use Pyomo to minimize the sum of the k largest values of a vector with weights

Tags: pyomo, portfolio

1. 

Thinking about Conditional Value-at-Risk (CVaR) optimization problem in spectral risk measure form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_risk_measure), for portfolio construction.

a. Original problem:

[image]

b. Second problem (R_2=-R_1):

[image]

c. Bilevel optimization:

[image]

$R$ is a tall random matrix of shape around $100000\times1000$.

$\mathbf{p}$ is a univariate probability mass function of an arbitrary distribution within $(0,1)$. $\mathbf{p}$ matches with each row of the sorted $R\mathbf{w}$. All elements in $\mathbf{p}$ are positive and ideally, they have a sum equal to $1$. **$\mathbf{p}$ can be sorted as well.**

Here I rewrite the 'Sort' part using permutation matrix $M$. It is okay to assume the 'Sort' as increasing or decreasing ($\text{Sort} \left[R\mathbf{w} \right]^T \mathbf{p}$ as largest element with largest weight or largest element with smallest weight).
**The 'Sort' part can be relaxed, a weak approximation is acceptable.**

Noticed that 'the sum of top k values (with non-increasing weights)' is LP representable, but please let me know if this problem could be solved by Pyomo.
https://yalmip.github.io/command/sumk/
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030505481930019X

2.
Also wondering if Value-at-Risk (VaR) optimization problem could also be solved by Pyomo?
[image]